# What is the best common technology to store data locally for mobile apps?

Tags: android, ios, database, mobile, windows-phone

I want to do an app for the three platforms : Android, Apple, Windows and I want to know what is the best choice to store local data on devices, to have a common data base, easily reusable for each platform ?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sqlite is likely to be supported on all 3 platforms, and is fairly powerful and widely supported.

As to the "best", that's an opinion, and even if there was an objective "best fit", the best fit would be different depending on the needs of your project.

Comment: Ok thanks it correspond to what I found